# ayuda no se porque el while no me funciona

Tags: c++, while

Se supone que con lo el while lo limita por la cantidad de alumnos que ingresa el usuario, pero no se que esta mal, ayuda porfavor

la idea del programa, es que el usuario ingrese la cantidad de alumnos, las notas de cada alumno y  al final dar el promedio genera de las notas de los alumnos

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int alum;
int cont=0;
int nota=0;
float promnota;

int main()
{
  cout<<"ingresar la cantidad total de alumnos de ese colegio" <<endl;
  cin>>alum;



  while(cont <= alum)
      {

        cout<<"ingrese nota"<<endl;
        cin>>nota;

        nota++;

      }

    cont++;

    promnota= nota/alum;
    cout<<"el promedio de notas"<<promnota;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Nota: esto soluciona sólo el problema con el `while` que se indicaba en la pregunta. **El código tiene otros errores** que hará que falle pero que quedan fuera del alcance de la pregunta original (por ejemplo, no se debería hacer `nota++` sino sumar la nota introducida a un total de notas).

El problema está en dónde tienes las llaves del `while` y que la actualización de la variable `cont` se produce fuera de ellas.

Tal y como está formateado el código y los espacios podría parecer que el `cont++` está dentro del while, pero realmente está fuera, por lo que nunca se actualizará y tu bucle `while` será un bucle infinito (porque `cont` será siempre 0 y menor que el número introducido como número de alumnos).

Aquí tienes el código con un espaciado diferente donde es más obvio el problema:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int alum;
int cont = 0;
int nota = 0;
float promnota;

int main() {
  cout << "ingresar la cantidad total de alumnos de ese colegio" << endl;
  cin >> alum;

  while (cont <= alum) {
    cout << "ingrese nota" << endl;
    cin >> nota;
    nota++;
  }

  cont++;

  promnota = nota / alum;
  cout << "el promedio de notas" << promnota;
}
```

La solución: mover `cont++` dentro del bucle `while`:

```
  while (cont <= alum) {
    cout << "ingrese nota" << endl;
    cin >> nota;
    nota++;
    cont++;
  }
```